# My website on iPhone 12 Pro looks different from LT Broswer (emulator), Firefox Dev, and Chrome Dev. How to solve?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, responsive

Hope everyone is ok.

I have been experiencing an issue where the padding looks like this on emulators and dev tools. [Emulator screenshot, it looks the same on Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e4Lb.png).

The problem is that it doesn't resemble what other people and myself have been experiencing. I have an iPhone 12 Pro and it looks like this [Screenshot from my iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWDS8.png).

I have been trying everything online but doesn't seem to help. I also added a lot of Custom CSS (I'm using Wordpress) to try and solve it without accomplishing it. Any help is appreciated.

PS: I have cleared the cache on my iPhone multiple times and checked if it's looking the same in other devices.